# Backup multiple Operating Systems

Tags: backup

I have Windows 7 and Fedora Linux in my system. I want format the system completely. So how to take back up of both OS and their partition easily? I'm preferring to do the backups of both OSes from Fedora itself? So is it possible? If so, How?

Comment: [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) *only*. I would migrate this question to [SU], but it's borderline asking for product reccomendations, which is off-topic on any [se] site. If you're having trouble with a particular product, please ask away, but asking what product(s) you should use will get closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dd1.html) to copy the disk sectors directly to a file on a removable drive, but you shouldn't copy a running system that way. Some of the files will be in use and the filesystem could get corrupted. It would be safer to boot to a [Live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and do the copy from there. Alternatively, though a little more challenging, you could remount your root partition read-only:

```
mount -o remount,ro /
```

...and then do the `dd` copy, but most of your running daemons won't tolerate a read-only filesystem.

Comment: Note: This will result in having files that are images of the original drives. It's not too hard to mount them and read their contents, but the user will not be able to double click on them like an archive file or something that easy. I do use this method for a variety of things, just not when end users are involved.